# Does pytest provide a way of automatically reading properties for a test from a yml or conf file?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, configuration-files

I'm using Python 3.8 and pytest for unit testing.  I have tests similar to the following

```
def test_insert_record(az_sql_db_inst):
    """."""
    foreign_key_id = 10
```

I don't like hard-coding "10" in the file, and would prefer this be stored in some external configuration file where other tests can also access the value.  Does pytest provide a way to do this (to load the values from a properties or yml file)?  I could just open a file on my own, e.g.

```
def test_insert_record(az_sql_db_inst):
    """."""
    file = open('test.txt')
    for line in file:
        fields = line.strip().split()
        foreign_key_id = fields[0]
```

but it seems like there is something that can automatically do that for me.

Comment: There are third-party plugins like [`pytest-yaml`](https://github.com/Benabra/pytest_yaml) or [`pytest-env`](https://github.com/MobileDynasty/pytest-env). You can also put your own key value pairs into `pytest.ini` and read them via `pytestconfig.getini('mykey')`. However, the question is rather why you would move out hardcoded values out of the test. This adds unncessary complexity and makes the test harder to read. Using named constants if you want to give a constant some meaning is usually enough.

Comment: I tried pytest-yaml, but I think it is a little out of date and not too well maintained.

Comment: [`pytest-yaml` is just a simple fixture](https://github.com/Benabra/pytest_yaml/blob/5c45f9f8367322bee21349059ab64767a2f4cde1/pytest_yaml/plugin.py#L20-L23), you can easily rewrite it yourself. I'm not even sure it was worth to put it into a separate plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to initialize some constants, a separated config.py would do the trick.

```
from config import foreign_key_id
```

And PyYAML package would be good if you prefer general-purpose text files.

However, if you want to specify expected test results or even different results depending on scenarios, [@pytest.mark.parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html) may be a good option.

Comment: "And PyYAML package would be good if you prefer general-purpose text files" is definitely what I prefer -- do you know some out-of-the-box solution or do I need to roll my own test fixture for this?